# Excel VBA ADODB Late Binding error

Tags: vba, excel, vb6-migration

Actually every time I am using the Early binding code to use the ADODB Connection , However now I want to use the Late Binding Code.
According to me, it seems the code is perfect but I don't the how I am getting an error Like "Argument are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or in conflict with one another."

```
Sub Test()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.JET.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=Y:\Operational Non Sensitive\Avon UK\UK Voice Productivity\UK AHT Report_.mdb"
rs.Open "Table1", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: getting the error while opening the the recordset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are late binding so enums like `adOpenDynamic`/`adLockOptimistic` do not exist & default to empty variants.

Define them within your code as consts, [ADOVBS.INC](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111655/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/code/adovbs.txt) lists their names & values.

```
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, Your Code helps me a Lot.